# Compute value entered in textbox and place in another textbox?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form with two text boxes. I want to enter a number on one box, press the Convert link, and have it compute the number in the first box to Celsius and place it in the second text box. So far it isn't working and I feel like there's something small I'm missing... What can I do?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<style type="text/css">
body
{
background-color: white;
}

h2
{
position: absolute;
left:200px;
top:5px;
color: cadetblue;
}
p
{
text-align: center;
font-family: times new roman;
color: black;
}
</style>
<script>
        function f2cCalc(input)
    {
        var fbox = document.getElementById(input);
        var cbox = document.getElementById(cinput);
       var f = parseInt(fbox.value);
       var cel = Math.round(5/9*(f-32));
       document.getElementById(cbox).value=cel;
      }
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="get" action="">

    <h2>Temp calculator</h2>
<br />
<br />
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        F<input id="finput" type="number" STYLE="background-color: cadetblue; color: green;" value="0"/>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        C<input id="cinput" type="number" STYLE="background-color: cadetblue; color: green;" value="0"/>

        <a href="javascript:f2cCalc(finput)">Convert</a>

        </form>
    </body>
</html>

enter code here
```

Comment: What does "isn't working" mean? What errors do you get? Have you tried debugging via the browser's console?

Answer (score 0):

These two lines might be causing your problem:

```
var fbox = document.getElementById(input);
var cbox = document.getElementById(cinput);
```

Change to:

```
var fbox = document.getElementById(input);
var cbox = document.getElementById('cinput');
```

Basically JavaScript is trying to load the id from a variable instead of the DOM.

Comment: I tried this as well as the above mentioned comment and still nothing happens when I click Convert... I think I got it working! Here's what I changed: function f2cCalc(input)
    {
        var fbox = input;
        var cbox = document.getElementById('cinput');
       var f = parseInt(fbox.value);
       var cel = Math.round(5/9*(f-32));
       cbox.value=""+cel;
       
    }

Answer (score 0):

You have typo in your code. Belwo mentioned three lines are the problem.

Change

```
 var fbox = document.getElementById(input);
 var cbox = document.getElementById(cinput);
 document.getElementById(cbox).value=cel;
```

to

```
 var fbox = document.getElementById('finput');
 var cbox = document.getElementById('cinput');
 cbox.value=cel;
```

<kbd>**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uTvsb/)**</kbd>

Comment: Still isn't doing anything when I click the Convert button... =/  EDIT I got it working, here's what I did: function f2cCalc(input)
    {
        var fbox = input;
        var cbox = document.getElementById('cinput');
       var f = parseInt(fbox.value);
       var cel = Math.round(5/9*(f-32));
       cbox.value=""+cel;
       
    }

Comment: @user2537100 Its working fine. check demo fiddle once. which browser you are using?

Answer (score 0):

you need little modifications

```
<a href="javascript:f2cCalc('finput')">Convert</a>
```

And

```
var cbox = document.getElementById('cinput');
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bd6wN/)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just hook into the input 'keyup' event? First, put your script and function definition below your inputs, within your `body`. Then, make your input selectors global.

```
<input id="finput" type="number" />
<input id="cinput" type="number" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    // I run once, _after_ the inputs are DOM ready.
    const FBOX = document.getElementById('finput')
    const CBOX = document.getElementById('cinput')
    FBOX.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
        let value = CBOX.value
        try {
            value = f2cCalc(parseInt(e.target.value))
        }
        CBOX.value = value
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function call should be like:

```
 <a href="javascript:f2cCalc('finput')">Convert</a>
```